# How to draw a diagram without using graphics

Tags: graphics

How to draw a diagram without using graphics. Using only text or math mode?
[image]

Comment: You can just use tikz and draw directly inside LaTeX.

Comment: I would like to do without Tikz @daleif

Comment: What counts as graphics? Picture mode? And can you just explain why you do not want tikz or similar, because those tools fit very well for these kind of things.

Comment: Please explain why? Drawing a frame around a letter is the same as tikz or micture mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This uses `\fbox`, `\rule` and `\makebox`.  The top line is actually wider than the bottom, but since they are centered it works out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\def\myrule{\rule[0.7ex]{1em}{\fboxrule}}%
\def\myfbox#1{\fbox{\makebox[1em]{#1}}}% use a constant width box
\def\mybox#1{\makebox[\dimexpr 2em+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule]{#1}}%

\mybox{3}\mybox{7}\mybox{8}\mybox{12}\mybox{14}\mybox{15}\mybox{18}\mybox{20}

\myfbox{B}\myrule\myfbox{C}\myrule\myfbox{D}\myrule\myfbox{E}\myrule\myfbox{F}%
  \myrule\myfbox{G}\myrule\myfbox{H}\myrule\myfbox{A}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ John I was curious how it looked so I compiled your code and then added a screenshot, hope that's ok.

Comment: No problem.  I just didn't bother.

Comment: Thanks @John Kormylo

Answer (score 10):

If you have a font that contains box drawing characters then you can draw the boxes using those characters, for example using the font DejaVu Sans Mono as follows (compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
 3   7   8  12  14  15  18  20
┌─┐ ┌─┐ ┌─┐ ┌─┐ ┌─┐ ┌─┐ ┌─┐ ┌─┐
│B├─┤C├─┤D├─┤E├─┤F├─┤G├─┤H├─┤A│
└─┘ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the line characters do not connect perfectly, here the top is slightly off but on other zoom levels it may be the bottom or the sides or any combination of visible segment joins. Note also that it is not really possible to center all numbers if you have both odd-length and even-length numbers.